# Rails flash message password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I need an Idea of making flash message with password

I have an application which has a posts and what I need is that when someone try to edit the post or delete it a message will asked for password...please note that I don't want or have the users, just simply I want to have one password as flash message, please just tell me how to make it

Comment: you need popup window, not flash message )))

Answer (score 0):

put the following code on your posts controller

```
http_basic_authenticate_with name: "root", password: "passpass", except: [:index, :show]
```

Comment: it sure works on rails 4 too http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html

Comment: Yeah thats right its working but when I replace the :index with the edit Its not working, cuz I want this to work only with the edit link if they enter the correct data then they can edit it

Comment: http_basic_authenticate_with name: "root", password: "passpass", only: [:edit, :delete]

Comment: yes thats working thank youuuu, but only with the edit and the delete not

Comment: http_basic_authenticate_with name: "root", password: "passpass", only: :edit

Comment: NO I just change the method name from delete to destroy and its working for both, thank you very much this was so helpful